# Positioning colorbar keeping tight_layout function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, colorbar

I used two colorbars for two plots in one figure with tight_layout. As a result, one vertical colorbar seems to too long and I would like to resize it. So, I coded as below:

```
CS1 = plt.contourf(X1,Y1,Z1,15,cmap=plt.cm.Greys,
              vmax=abs(Z1).max(), vmin=abs(Z1).min())
q = np.max(z[1:275])
position=fig.add_axes([0.93,0.1,0.02,0.35])  
cb = fig.colorbar(CS1,cax=position)
cb.set_label(r'Terrain Height [m]')
plots = []
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=np.min(z[1:275]), vmax=q))
sm._A = []
for i in range(1,275):
      cs2=plt.plot(lon[i], lat[i], c=cm.rainbow(z[i]/q),marker='o',  ms=3,markeredgecolor='none')
    plots.append(cs2)

cb1=plt.colorbar(sm,orientation='horizontal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlim(103.895,104.105)
plt.ylim(40.815,40.975)
```

I would like to keep the tight_layout and xlim and ylim. However, when I use this position fuction as shown above, it seems to crash with tight_layout cancelling out the x and y limit.

Would you please give me any idea to resize and move the vertical colorbar keeping tight_layout and x and y limit.

Thank you,
Isaac